# I m Getting error while inserting queries android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: contacts.id (code 1299)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is the insert code from my signup class.  I'm getting:

> (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: contacts.id (code 1299))

```
if (R.id.bRegister == v.getId()) {
    EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswprd);
    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

    String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
    String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
    String passstr = pass.getText().toString();

    Contact c = new Contact();

    c.setUname(unamestr);
    c.setEmail(emailstr);
    c.setPass(passstr);
    helper.insertContact(c);
    Toast temp = Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Register Done ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    temp.show();
}
```

**EDIT** insertContact is:

```
public void insertContact(Contact c) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String query = " select *from contacts ";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    values.put(COLUMN_UNAME, c.getUname());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, c.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Please share the code of `insertContact` and the definition of your table

Comment: public void insertContact(Contact c)
        {
            db=this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values= new ContentValues();

            String query = " select *from contacts ";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query ,null);
            int count = cursor.getCount();

            values.put(COLUMN_UNAME, c.getUname());
            values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, c.getEmail());
            values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());

            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null ,values);
            db.close();
        }

Comment: Add it as an edit to the question, not in the comments as many users don't look through here for details on the question

Comment: This: NOT NULL constraint failed: contacts.id, means you're trying to create a contact record without giving it an ID.

Comment: Please share also on how you create the table.

Comment: At a guess you have something different to `CREATE TABLE contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ......` that includes NOT NULL e.g. you may have `id INTEGER NOT NULL`. The first is special in that it says the **id** column is an alias of the **rowid** column, in which case the value is set by sqlite if it isn't supplied. The latter by coding NOT NULL is saying that you MUST supply a value. You'd need to provide the code where the TABLE is defined/created for a more specific answer.